# Android-GraphQL-Apollo client - Query unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, android-jetpack-compose, apollo-client

I am trying to integrate graphql in my android project.My package name is app.android.mylife.
I have set
 `apollo { packageName.set("app.android.mylife") }`
in my gradle file.

I created the same package structure for graphql folder also.
main-graphql-app-android-mylife->(here all graphql files)
I am having schema.json file which is also integrated .
And defined the query like this
[test query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTpUo.png).
When i execute this query with graphql plugin in android studio it gives response properly.
Then i rebuilt the project.
When i use the auto generated class BlogPostsQuery, it give unresolved refernce when compiled.
How can i solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.